# AspNetCore.Http 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext'

Tags: asp.net-core, owin, owin-middleware

we are using AspNetCore.Http with `MyController : Controller`. How do I get Get OwinContext `this.Request.GetOwinContext();` doesnt work.

'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' and the best extension method overload 'OwinHttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpRequestMessage)' requires a receiver of type 'HttpRequestMessage'

Answer (score 1):

**ASP.NET Core:**

- Supports the [Open Web Interface for `.NET` (OWIN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
- Has .NET Core compatible replacements for the `Microsoft.Owin.* (Katana)` libraries.

**OWIN** allows web apps to be decoupled from web servers. It defines a standard way for middleware to be used in a pipeline to handle requests and associated responses. **ASP.NET Core** applications and middleware can interoperate with `OWIN-based` applications, servers, and middleware.

**OWIN** provides a decoupling layer that allows two frameworks with disparate object models to be used together.

[image]

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` package provides two adapter implementations:

- ASP.NET Core to OWIN
- OWIN to ASP.NET Core

This allows **ASP.NET Core** to be hosted on top of an **OWIN** compatible server/host or for other **OWIN** compatible components to be run on top of **ASP.NET Core**.

---

**Note**:

Using these adapters comes with a performance cost. **Apps using only ASP.NET Core components shouldn't use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin package or adapters.**

Comment: How do I get owincontext or owin's IDictionary<string,object> in this usecase. It's not shared in docs either.

Comment: You could only run OWIN middleware in the ASP.NET Core pipeline but not in ASP.NET Core controller.

Comment: `GetOwinContext()` is a part of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly using the `ASP.NET` not `ASP.NET Core`. You could use `HttpContext.Authentication` in `ASP.NET Core` apps.

Comment: I am trying to do something with websockets so not really sure how `HttpContext.Authentication` will be helpful. I need to access `IDictionary<string,object>` object of Owin. Even in pipelines, how do I access the owin context or `IDictionary<string,object>` in asp.net core?

Comment: Check [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.OwinEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.owin.owinenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Here is a demo of [OwinSample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/owin/sample/src/OwinSample/Startup.cs)